# IBM APIC starting loopback

Tags: json, strongloop, loopback, apiconnect

I am new to API Connect, and I have installed npm, node and apic in my local MacBook. Now I have created a loopback directory and trying to run the loopback application using apic Start. However, I am not understanding the error received from the logs:

MacBook-Pro-2:socialreviews Work$ apic start

Error: Service socialreviews started but did not initialize within the timeout period. Dumping log buffer.
[Tue Apr 30 12:02:42 2019] com.ibm.diagnostics.healthcenter.loader INFO: Node Application Metrics 3.1.3.201810251210 (Agent Core 3.2.6)
[Tue Apr 30 12:02:42 2019] com.ibm.diagnostics.healthcenter.mqtt INFO: Connecting to broker localhost:1883
strong-supervisor attaching dashboard at /appmetrics-dash
2019-04-30T09:02:42.694Z pid:44844 worker:0 INFO supervisor starting (pid 44844)
2019-04-30T09:02:42.697Z pid:44844 worker:0 INFO supervisor reporting metrics to `internal:`
2019-04-30T09:02:42.709Z pid:44844 worker:0 INFO supervisor size set to undefined
2019-04-30T09:02:42.905Z pid:44848 worker:1 [Tue Apr 30 12:02:42 2019] com.ibm.diagnostics.healthcenter.loader INFO: Node Application Metrics 3.1.3.201810251210 (Agent Core 3.2.6)
2019-04-30T09:02:42.959Z pid:44848 worker:1 [Tue Apr 30 12:02:42 2019] com.ibm.diagnostics.healthcenter.mqtt INFO: Connecting to broker localhost:1883
2019-04-30T09:02:42.995Z pid:44848 worker:1 strong-supervisor attaching dashboard at /appmetrics-dash
2019-04-30T09:02:45.017Z pid:44848 worker:1 Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:4004
2019-04-30T09:24:29.148Z pid:44844 worker:0 WARN received SIGTERM, shutting down
2019-04-30T09:24:29.148Z pid:44844 worker:0 INFO supervisor size set to undefined
2019-04-30T09:24:29.148Z pid:44844 worker:0 INFO supervisor stopped

Can someone help me with this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved, however I am not 100% sure what was the exact issue. What I have done is ran *apic edit* command then when clicking on start it suddenly asked me to install docker. I have done so, then I started to have readable errors of some packages not installed. So I used npm commands to install them and my issue is fixed now! :)